# How do I use this SQL Stored Procedure to create an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

A workmate has given me this stored procedure and asked for help to create an sql INSERT statement based on its results, but am a little confused to some of the methods.  For example, I've never seen a CASE statement in sql.  I looked it up but the useage is different from what I was given.

Here is the stored procedure

```
if @ScheduleType Is Null
SELECT Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleType, 
SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 1 THEN CASE WHEN (LEFT(DATENAME(Month, 
                    3)) = 'JAN' THEN ItemQty END END) AS I01,
SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 1 THEN CASE WHEN (LEFT(DATENAME(Month,                  
                    Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleDate), 3)) 
                  = 'FEB' THEN ItemQty END END) AS I02, 
SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 2 THEN ItemQty ELSE 0 END) AS PRD,
LmpProjectInfo.PlannedQty, 
LmpProjectInfo.AuthorizedQty, 
LmpProjectInfo.WbsElementID

FROM Item_Schedule 
INNER JOIN Lu_Schedule_Types 
          ON Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleType = Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleTypeId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN LmpProjectInfo 
          ON Item_Schedule.ItemWbsElement = LmpProjectInfo.WbsElementID
WHERE
    (Item_Schedule.IsActive = 1) 
    AND (Item_Schedule.ItemWbsElement = @WbsElement) 
    AND (Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate)) AND 
    (Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleDate >= @StartDate)
GROUP BY Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleType
    , Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleTypeId
    , LmpProjectInfo.PlannedQty
    , LmpProjectInfo.AuthorizedQty
    , LmpProjectInfo.WbsElementID
ORDER BY Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleTypeId
```

I am supposed to be helping him out but I'm by far a database wizard, and am a little out of my depth here.  I'd really appreciate the help/advice/direction.

Thanks much!

Comment: Tell them you are out of your depth.

Comment: i did hehe.  its at the bottom.

Comment: hm, I am not sure how you could get something from the 'results' of this procedure since there are no results but a single insert. (results are most commonly known as that what comes back from a select)

Comment: Apologies, its a select.  Edited.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quick sample that might work for you. This assumes that the table you want to insert data into takes all of the values return from the `SELECT` statement and that they are of the same type.

As a side note, the reason you might have got a bit confused about the `CASE` statements is possibly due to the fact there are two main ways to use them in SQL. `CASE WHEN...` like you have here and `CASE #value# WHEN #result# THEN...`. A little more searching on the web will lead you to some nice examples. For example [this one](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/).

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
(
    ScheduleType,
    I01,
    I02,
    PRD,
    PlannedQty,
    AuthorizedQty,
    WbsElementID
)
SELECT
Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleType, 
SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 1 THEN CASE WHEN (LEFT(DATENAME(Month, 
                    3)) = 'JAN' THEN ItemQty END END) AS I01,
SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 1 THEN CASE WHEN (LEFT(DATENAME(Month,                  Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleDate), 3)) 
                  = 'FEB' THEN ItemQty END END) AS I02, 
SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 2 THEN ItemQty ELSE 0 END) AS PRD,
LmpProjectInfo.PlannedQty, 
LmpProjectInfo.AuthorizedQty, 
LmpProjectInfo.WbsElementID

FROM
    Item_Schedule INNER JOIN
    Lu_Schedule_Types ON Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleType = Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleTypeId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    LmpProjectInfo ON Item_Schedule.ItemWbsElement = LmpProjectInfo.WbsElementID
WHERE
    (Item_Schedule.IsActive = 1) AND (Item_Schedule.ItemWbsElement = @WbsElement) AND 
    (Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate)) AND 
    (Item_Schedule.ItemScheduleDate >= @StartDate)
GROUP BY Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleType, Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleTypeId,
    LmpProjectInfo.PlannedQty, LmpProjectInfo.AuthorizedQty, 
    LmpProjectInfo.WbsElementID
ORDER BY Lu_Schedule_Types.ScheduleTypeId
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 -- insert in table
(
      ScheduleType
    , I01
    , I02
    , PRD
    , PlannedQty
    , AuthorizedQty
    , WbsElementID
)
SELECT 
      t.ScheduleType
    , I01 = SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 1 AND MONTH(s.ItemScheduleDate) = 1 THEN ItemQty END) 
    , I02 = SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 1 AND MONTH(s.ItemScheduleDate) = 2 THEN ItemQty END)  
    , PRD = SUM(CASE WHEN InductionProduction = 2 THEN ItemQty END) 
    , i.PlannedQty
    , i.AuthorizedQty
    , i.WbsElementID
--INTO #temp_table -- or insert in temp table
FROM dbo.Item_Schedule s
JOIN dbo.Lu_Schedule_Types t ON s.ItemScheduleType = t.ScheduleTypeId 
RIGHT JOIN dbo.LmpProjectInfo i ON s.ItemWbsElement = i.WbsElementID
WHERE s.IsActive = 1
    AND s.ItemWbsElement = @WbsElement 
    AND s.ItemScheduleDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate))
    AND s.ItemScheduleDate >= @StartDate
GROUP BY 
      t.ScheduleType
    , t.ScheduleTypeId
    , i.PlannedQty
    , i.AuthorizedQty
    , i.WbsElementID
ORDER BY t.ScheduleTypeId
```